# Clojure namespace: method to see defined objects?

Tags: clojure

Is there some way to see what has already been defined in a clojure session (equivalent to calling ls())?  Let's say that I create a few objects:

```
(def x 1)
(def y 2.2)
(def plus-one (fn [x] (+ x 1)))
```

Is there a command that can be run to show me that these now exist in the user namespace?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am doing all the assignments in user namespace.

```
user> (def *foo 10) 
#'user/*foo
```

;; To see all the public intern mappings in the user namespace.

```
user> (ns-publics 'user)
{*foo #'user/*foo}
```

Now let's define a function which is not public

```
user> (defn- foobar[x]
        (println x)
#'user/foobar
```

When you call ns-publics function. It will not show foobar function in the mappings.

```
user> (ns-publics 'user)
{*foo #'user/*foo}
```

To see the intern mappings for the namespace. Use (ns-interns 'YOUR-NAMESPACE)

```
user> (ns-interns 'user)
{foobar #'user/foobar, *foo #'user/*foo}
```

Comment: Oh, so that's what `ns-interns` is for! +1 but I'm out of votes ;)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe `ns-publics` ?

> Returns a map of the public intern mappings for the namespace.

or `ns-map` ?

> Returns a map of all the mappings for the namespace.

---

As I understand it, there is no "global environment," there are only namespaces. Of course whichever one you are currently "in" looks like a "global environment" for practical purposes.